# Champion picking

Tags: league-of-legends

I am currently a lvl 20 player in League of Legends but seeing as im playing plenty lately i am preparing for the tougher opponents instead of the trolling players. So i was wondering what champion to pick against certain champs. I know this is a very large question but i simply need the idea. So if (for example) mundo counters darius (tank counters bruiser).

For example [Darius counters Teemo.](http://bromacia.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/play-teemo-they-said.jpg)  But Darius is weak against Jayce.

This is just one example and a specific one but im simply asking for a global explanation so tanky champions counter bruisers. etc. Bonus points awarded for one who gives a complete and entire list (although this is a massive task).

Some explaining would be greatly appreciated.

Ok although i've received some decent answers its still to champion oriented. I would be happy with a general assumption of what kind of champs counter which. So bruiser counters tank, tank counters adc. (examples ofc).

The bonus points awarded to a full list (so the answer of the question + a list of champions).

Comment: This is a huge list. Check here for information: http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/counter-picks-against-each-individual-champion-177707#chapter4 when i am home i might put all this into an answer if i have time.

Comment: How well you play the champion is also a big factor - don't get too discouraged if you think the enemy champion is a counter to you.

Comment: [LoL Counter](http://www.lolcounter.com)

Comment: I don't think this question has an answer.  Counters are determined by a champions kit, not the role they fill.

Comment: This is far too huge to be properly answered.  You would have to list each champion, who they counter, and who counters them.  For a proper answer, you'd also have to include strategies for each pairing, and probably items to buy, too.  Skill and familiarity will also play a part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to narrow down this (indeed) large question.

First of all I will have to disagree that tanks counter bruisers.
I will also disagree that darius counters teemo.
A good link to see specifics on who counters who is this: **[lolcounter](http://www.lolcounter.com/)**

But in general, I would say that the best way to counter any champion is to see what he can do and think of a champion that thrives under those conditions.

For example Darius is an exceptionally good dueler. Which basically means that if you get close to him he will most likely beat you to death. He also has a pull to get you close to him which is pretty close range though. So what you need to  beat him is enough movement speed to stay away from his pull while being able to harass him from a distance. It seems to me that both Jayce AND Teemo are good for this task. Teemo has passively increased movement speed from his W, has one the best harassing mechanisms in the game and even if by any chance you get caught, blinding darius can win you some time to get away again using your W active and any escaping summoner spells you might have.
You have to be a very careless teemo in order to lose to ANY ad melee bruiser without a jump or a gap closer of some kind.

So here is an answer to your question. If played correctly Teemo counters the majority of ad bruisers @ top.

Lets say you have someone that jumps/dashes in your face like jax, irelia, xin zhao, diana. Those champions could be a problem for Teemo right? 
Well then you need someone that excels at close range or that has a good area of dominance.

In my personal opinion a good champion to counter those dashers is Yorick. Anyone who jumps on Yorick will get punished by having 3 ghouls in his face. Yorick will win most trades and yorick will have more sustain in the lane.

Garen can also punish those jumpers, because if you jump on a garen you will get silenced and spinned, and if he times his shield correctly he will most likely not get any damage. And when the fight is over Garen will sit off a bit and regen.

I 'm only talkin about top lane cause thats where you were heading with your Question.
And top lane is only 1v1. Sometimes you have to see the whole picture. For example if you see the opponents having a Kennen or a Fiddlesticks you have to think to yourself: "What is the main strength of those champions?" and the answer would be that they have devastating and potentially game changing area of effect (AOE) Ultimates. The you ask yourself: "Well how to I stop them from destroying my entire team in teamfights?" and the answwer would be I can shield my entire team to negate the damage or I can just push them out of the teamfightwhen they use their ultimates. Then you ask yourself: "Who can push them out?", "Alistar can but its only for 1 champion, is there someone who can do for more of them (if there are more than 1)?" Answer is Janna (Ultimate). And thats basically how it goes.

But really check out the link I gave you cause it's really really useful for this task.

**EDIT**:

So regarding the general guidelines you were asking for.

The problem is that Roles do not matter when it comes to countering someone. I mean you can't say with absolute certainty that Tanks counter ADCs because there are certain ADCs like Vayne for example that can easily kill tanks late game due to the fact that they do true damage to them every 3 hits. With enough attack speed Vayne can choke down the health of almost any tank despite any armor. 
The answer to what counters Vayne is: Reduction of Attack Speed, which one can find in Frozen Heart or Malphite's (E) Ground Slam.

But you see the problem here is if I told you Tanks counter ADCs which is true for the majority of the champions you could easily pick lets say Mundo against a Vayne and lose.

The key in Countering are **Mechanics** not **Roles**.
That is why I insist that if you can't (which is absolutely normal if you're level 20) think on your own about your opponents mechanics and what/who counters them then just use this really useful tool that I gave you which ALSO suggests items and summoner spells against every champion.

**EDIT2**:

Well luckily enough I found this spreadsheet with the full list that you wanted. I Reviewed it a bit to see if I agree with it and it looks ok on most parts so there you go: 
**[Full Lol Counter List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?hl=en_US%5D&hl=en_US%5D&key=0Aq-068L0cPIZdHdZR3JtaXlOdTZWQjJVb3FoUVZLM1E&type=view%20&gid=0&f=true&sortcolid=-1&sortasc=true&rowsperpage=250)**

Comment: thanks for the comment, please check my improved question.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Hi Marco, like I said there are 2 main issues here: We can't possibly give a Full list of champions since there are well over 100 champions in the game. It would be unpractical I think. It's really easy to type the name of the champion you want in Lol Counter and the website will tell you who people voted as the best counter for that champion and additional info as well. Regarding the General guidelines I will add a new paragraph in my answer to explain why you Can't have them. Feel free to comment further though!

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma At the bottom of my answer I included a spreadsheet with a full list of counters which seems pretty decent and updated. I hope this covers you ;)

Comment: You could have said http://www.championselect.net/ which is quite a great web site for Counterpicks.

Comment: @Fabinout I think its the exact same thing with a different layout.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos If it's true, it's genius ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would advice that you use championselect.net if you need help determining in-lane counters, BUT you should not be playing a certain champion for the sake of "countering".

Pick a champion that matches your play style, play the easy and hard matchups with them. There is no point in counter picking if you are mechanically worse with the selected champion. You will need to understand the strengths and weaknesses of your champion versus particular matchups.

Picked Riven versus Teemo? He certainly gives close range bruisers a hard time. Evaluate how mechanicly good your opponent is witht hat champion, this should determine your level of aggression. Learn to tower farm and play it safe during harder matchups when your opponent is on par or superior than you. Realize that while Teemo would be troublesome to deal with in lane, during teamfights you have the upper edge with two forms of crowd control.

With that said here is a personal list of champions (I've played) which represent a particular playstyle and are relatively safe to play as.

Top:

Vladamir/Nidalee: Hit or miss champions, some people are instantly good with them others might take a while to get used to their more passive playstyle. Weak early game (Vlad is particularly weaker), will generally poke their opponents down while healing back the majority of the damage dealt to them.

Irelia/Shen: Weak laning phase, stronger mid/lategame. Irelia is a reliable initiator + anticarry while shen's ultimate allows him to consistently test the enemy teams mobility and ability to react to side push (which many fail miserably).

Renekton/Darius/Riven: Depending on the matchup these three can catch some players off-guard. Good damage and tower diving potential, can result in a very aggressive laning phase.

Cho'Gath: Safe laner, even when losing lane can still make a huge difference in teamfights with his feast and built in large health pool.

Mid:

Malzahar: Easiest laner in the entire game. Very few mids can actually contest him 1 vs. 1, only problem is during teamfights Malz tends to have terrible positioning as a result of his ultimate.

Morganna: Safe farmer, junglers will have a hard time ganking her with her spell shield off cooldown.

LeBlanc/Veigar: Love to burst players down. Veigar scales better into lategame. Much harder to farm with than the last two, but that's alright these players love to farm champions instead.

ADC:

Safe - Ezreal/Caitlin: Easy to learn and as safe as you can get for an ADC. Both get a jump and have an easier time zoning other ADCs. Although don't expect them to compete with a Kog'Maw or Vayne late game.

Aggressive - Draven/Sivir/Miss Fortune: Strong laners, with the right support can catch the enemy of guard. Miss Fortune has very good team synergi.

Lategame- Tristanna/Vayne/Kog'Maw:  Hard laning phase. Pentakill late game.

Support:

Passive - Soraka/Alistar/Janna: Focus more on either peeling for their ADC or simply giving them the sustain they need to remain in lane. (Contrary to his skill set Alistar is not an aggressive support, inexperienced players will be shocked as to how fast he can die... Use him to disengage). Soraka is extremely easy to play if new to support, simpyl stay back, maintain bush control, and be a heal/mana bot.

Passive-Agresive?: Sona/Nami/Lulu: Good zoning potential, sustain, and bring some form of CC to complement their ADC.

Agressive: Leona/Thresh/Blitzcranck: Love to initiate, can catch players off guard. Sustain is not a counter to this play style. Success depends mostly on skill, a good Lulu can keep these three so low they will be afraid to initiate while a good Leona will punish the enemy duo when their CC or jumps are on cooldown.

Oh and one more champion...

Elise: My personal favorite, play her top, mid, jungle, or support. Love her mobility, CC, and burst potential.

That's just a suggestion of certain champions that embody a particular playstyle, find one you like. Take counters with a grain of salt.

You will end in matchups were your picks don't entirely counter theirs. That's fine! Build a Negatron to counter their fed AP Carry or a Randuins to slow down their AD Heavy team. Items are also another great way of 'countering' mathcups.

TLDR: Pick a champion that complements your playstyle. Learn the weaknesses of your opponents champions.